# Print program's arguments with write function

Tags: c

I'm trying to print program's argument using `write` function, my program display garbage, my code looks good to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int ft_putchar(char c) {
    write(1,&c,1);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int b;
    i = 1;
    while(i < argc) {
        b =0;
        while(argv[i] != '\0') {
            ft_putchar(argv[i][b]);
            b++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: **Always** enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them! You will see.

Comment: my code compiles well and there are no errors, the problem it doesn't display the arguments. I use this when i compile `gcc -Werror file.c`

Comment: So you did not enable warnings! RTFM, section warning options!

Comment: Try with `-Wall`... -Werror only gives errors not warnings

Comment: The code compiles but now it doesn't display anything at all.

Comment: @Olaf In this case, even `-Weverything` doesn't catch the error. The reason is that the compiler sees `'\0'` as `0`, which is then interpreted as `NULL`.

Comment: @user3386109: Yes, after some hours sleep, that came into my mind, too. Again that rubbish _null pointer constant_ ambivalence of `(int)0`. Wish C11 had followed C++11 and introduced `nullptr` to eventually get rid of that rubbish in some future version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while loop is incorrect and it should be.

```
while(argv[i][b] != '\0')
```

Comment: Thanks. It was going to take a while for me to see that.